# Nginx access to images in backend folder

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2

My app store images on the backedn side in nodejs folder: /images.
After publish it to Ec2 I don't have an access to these images by url like: [www.domain.com/image01.jpg](http://www.domain.com/image01.jpg)

Configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
 charset utf-8;
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name _;

 location / {
   root /opt/front-end;
   try_files $uri /index.html;
 }

 location /images/ {
  root /opt/back-end/;
 }

 location /api/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
 }
}
```

[image]

Is it the configuration problem or permission or something else? I will be grateful for help!

Comment: `location /iamges/ {` is this your literal code :) ? If it's not that typo you'll need to provide more information - like what url doesn't work, the error message received, server logs, what file you're expecting that to return and demonstrating the file exists. Please replace any images of text with the text they contain.

Comment: I updated a little bit. No error messages, what I expect get images from that folder by url

Comment: None of my comment has been actioned - the example added (`by url like: www.domain.com/image01.jpg`) will obviously be handled by the `location /` block since it doesn't match anything else - Is _that_ a typo?  Make it easier for people to help you please :). -1, good luck.

Comment: AD7six please read carefully, I updated question and write 'images' correctly. If you can't understand something you can ask about it or skip it.

Comment: Respectfully, have you read more than the first few words of either of my comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct configuration should be:

```
server {
  charset utf-8;
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  location / {
    root /opt/front-end/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
  }

  location /images {
    autoindex on;
    alias /opt/back-end/images/;
  }
}
```